# New Windows 7 User having hard time adjusting to new Explorer

Tags: windows-7

As I navigate through the folder hierarchy using the top "drill down path" (which is new to Win 7 and cool), I miss seeing the tree on the left reflect my current selected folder location shown on the right. I'd like the selected folder in the tree on the tree to show the same current folder location on the right.

Is there any way to bring this functionality back?

Comment: I am unclear what you are asking.  Windows 7 has a tree on the left by default.  Can you post a screen shot of what you want or what you have that you want to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, then this worked for me:

1. Click on organize then folder and search options
2. In the general tab, under the navigation section, check both show all folders and automatically expand to current folder
3. Click OK

That should be it!

Comment: Excellent! I am feeling betetr already!

Answer (score 1):

Try [explorer++](http://www.explorerplusplus.com/) 
It is fast and you can store tabs as bookmarks to rapidly access documents, downloads etc.